# MySql: JOIN and SUM from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I need to sum-up the amount in 2 tables (c1, c2) linked n:1 to table a. The problem is: It would be greate if I could do it in just 1 query, because the real situation is a bit more complicated ;-) I brought it down to this testcase:

```
create table a (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table c1 (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, KEY(id),
`a` int(10),
`amount` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table c2 (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, KEY(id),
`a` int(10),
`amount` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO a SET id=1;
INSERT INTO c1 SET a=1, amount = 2;
INSERT INTO c1 SET a=1, amount = 3;
INSERT INTO c2 SET a=1, amount = 1;

SELECT SUM(c1.amount), SUM(c2.amount) 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c1 ON c1.a = a.id
LEFT JOIN c2 ON c2.a = a.id
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

The result of course is:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| SUM(c1.amount) | SUM(c2.amount) |
+----------------+----------------+
|           5.00 |           2.00 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

because c1 is joined twice and doubles the amound in c2. But I need to get:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| SUM(c1.amount) | SUM(c2.amount) |
+----------------+----------------+
|           5.00 |           1.00 |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Any idea how to get to this?

Comment: I think it is best to not ``SUM`` the two together, what benefit does it give you? Two separate SQLs would take less time (no JOIN, so it will be faster) and give you accurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer is:

```
SELECT (select SUM(c1.amount) from c1 where c1.a = a.id) as c1_amount, 
       (select SUM(c2.amount) from c2 where c2.a = a.id) as c2_amount 
FROM a
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51431/1)

BTW - Thanks for putting in the data and create scripts.  That helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine! How would you add another query on the same table, like: I want to get to know the count of entrys in c1 pointing to a. Would you add another subquery, like:
(select COUNT(c1.id) from c1 where c1.a = a.id) as c1_count
or is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
     , SUM(CASE WHEN b.source = 'c1' THEN amount END) c1_ttl
     , SUM(CASE WHEN b.source = 'c2' THEN amount END) c2_ttl 
  FROM a 
  JOIN 
     ( 
       SELECT *,'c1' source FROM c1 UNION SELECT *,'c2' FROM c2
     ) b 
    ON b.a = a.id;
+----+--------+--------+
| id | c1_ttl | c2_ttl |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |   5.00 |   1.00 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT SUM(c1.amount) FROM c1 WHERE c1.a = 1) C1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(c2.amount) FROM c2 WHERE c2.a = 1) C2;
```